# How can i create a "see-through" background?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to make the text have a background that masks the colored divs that scrolls behind it but shows the gradient background.
as if it has a fixed "window" that let see-throught and shows the backgorund.

https://codepen.io/santandrea/pen/wvrdmmj

```css
body {
  background-color: background: rgb(131, 58, 180);
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(131, 58, 180, 1) 0%, rgba(253, 29, 29, 1) 50%, rgba(252, 176, 69, 1) 100%);
}

#element {
  width: max-content;
  position: fixed;
  margin: 0 auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  top: 40vh
}

.box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}

.a {
  background-color: green;
}

.b {
  background-color: purple;
}

.c {
  background-color: grey;
}

.d {
  background-color: red;
}

section {
  max-width: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="element">
  text
</div>

<section>
  <div class="box a"></div>
  <div class="box b"></div>
  <div class="box c"></div>
  <div class="box d"></div>
  <div class="box a"></div>
  <div class="box b"></div>
  <div class="box c"></div>
  <div class="box d"></div>
</section>
```

Comment: You're asking if it's possible to make other elements transparent as they scroll behind the fixed element? So that only the background is visible behind the fixed element?

Comment: Please add the code you have written so far and explain where it isn't creating the effect you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, this answer is not ideal, and has some limitations.

As long as the main background has an attachment of `fixed`, you can give the fixed text box the same background and it will look "transparent".

This only works because the body and the text element share the same background.

```css
body {
  background-color: background: rgb(131, 58, 180);
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(131, 58, 180, 1) 0%, rgba(253, 29, 29, 1) 50%, rgba(252, 176, 69, 1) 100%);
}

#element {
  width: max-content;
  position: fixed;
  margin: 0 auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  top: 40vh;

  /* same background as body */
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(131, 58, 180, 1) 0%, rgba(253, 29, 29, 1) 50%, rgba(252, 176, 69, 1) 100%);
  /* this line is key to it working */
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}

.a {
  background-color: green;
}

.b {
  background-color: purple;
}

.c {
  background-color: grey;
}

.d {
  background-color: red;
}

section {
  max-width: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="element">
  text
</div>

<section>
  <div class="box a"></div>
  <div class="box b"></div>
  <div class="box c"></div>
  <div class="box d"></div>
  <div class="box a"></div>
  <div class="box b"></div>
  <div class="box c"></div>
  <div class="box d"></div>
</section>
```